# Printing integers between 2 given integers

Tags: java, for-loop, integer

I'm trying to create a class with a method that prints all integers between any two given integers. This is what I've got now-

```
public class IntList {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int stop = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
for (int i = start + 1; i < stop; i++) {
System.out.print(i);
}
}
```

}

This won't compile, I get 2 errors saying "reached end of file while parsing", once each for lines 4 and 5.

Comment: Ok. And what is the problem ?

Comment: System.out.print(i); prints in same line but printf adds a line feed easch.

Answer (score 4):

Wrong `main()` method declaration. You have to pass an array as the only parameter for this function.

Then either declare your **start** and **stop** variables as local, and do the job inside the main method itself, or create a new function you call from the `main()` method.

No more explanation needed, this is Java basics. You should read a Java lesson.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problem with this code

- Main method doesn't have proper signature

make main like

```
public static void main(String ar[]){
}
```

and create another static method to accept two int variable

- duplicate local variable declaration

remove

```
int i;
```

You already declare and initialize as a part of for loop

It will give you `duplicate local variable` error

Comment: The outer variable is being shadowed by that local-loop variable i.? Does that shadowed variable need this.i ?

Comment: @hus it will give you duplicate local variable error

Comment: thanks, removed i-- it still won't compile not sure why, says something about if start?

Comment: See updated answer, main method is not properly declared it should accept `String[] ar` instead of two `int`

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` method declaration is incorrect. The argument list in a Java application's `main` method is required to be a `String` array. Read the `start` and `stop` values from the first 2 values of the `String` array after removing the duplicate declaration of the variable `i`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int stop = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    for (int i = start + 1; i < stop; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to pass in the `start` & `stop` values to the application

```
java IntList 1 10
```

Comment: thanks, your answer seems like it should be doing exactly what I want it to do, but for some reason it still won't compile. I'm using vim and my String[], Integer. and System. aren't a different color- is it possible that I need to import something I'm missing?

Comment: Everything you're using is from `java.lang` to no need to import anything. What errors do you see? Update your question...

Answer (score 0):

You need `public static void main(String[])` in your class in order it to be executed.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class IntList {
    public static void main(int start, int stop){
        for (int i = start + 1; i < stop; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        main(random.nextInt(20),random.nextInt(100));
    }
}
```